# Verifying that a method was invoked from the constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, guice, mockito

I have a constructor which unfortunately must do something non-trivial:

```
public MyModule() {
    this.setInjector(Guice.createInjector(new AfterInjectionModule(
            PostConstruct.class, Matchers.any()), new MyGuiceModule()));
}
```

I now need to verify that the `AfterInjectionModule` was called in the scheme of things with the `PostConstruct.class` parameter. I couldn't care less about the other parameters for now. Unfortunately, I can't think of how I would `verify()` this in Mockito. I'm currently trying the following:

```
this.reference = mock(new MyModule());
verify(this.reference).setInjector(Guice.createInjector(
        new AfterInjectionModule(PostConstruct.class, Matchers.any()), 
        new MyGuiceModule()));
```

My unit test fails at the above line. How can I verify that this method was set to an `Injector` which was passed `AfterInjectionModule` with `PostConstruct.class` as its first parameter?

Comment: I would use `PowerMockito` and `mockNew`

Comment: Ok, how would I do that? Can you supply an answer with instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think the problem is not the mocking of the constructor, but rather the static call to Guice.createInjector(). Since you cannot mock a static method with Mockito, you can either try to verify the result from the behaviour (could be difficult) or use another tool like Powermock to override the static method.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than test for the actual invocation you should test whether MyModule behaves as expected if it did call `new AfterInjectionModule(PostConstruct.class, Matchers.any())` and that it does not behave as it would if it did not call it.

Given that this is about a Guice injector, verifying the behavior can be as simple as checking whether a class provided by the injector is actually an instance of a class that is provided by `AfterInjectionModule` initialized with those parameters.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is easier said than done. The `AfterInjectionModule` looks for annotations on Guice classes and calls init methods after they've been injected with all their dependencies. Unless there's a way for me to intercept this, I'm still out in cold.

Comment: You should probably then, consider whether this test is an integration test, rather than a unit test, and forego mocking altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You're in trouble here a little bit, because if you use Mockito you won't be using your own constructor anyway. Note that your code also puts slightly-more-heavy logic in your constructor, which is [not a good idea](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/).

If you want to stick with Mockito, factor out the instructor-setting code into a `init()` method that you can call from your test. If you really want to you can still call that method from your constructor, but you can also make it visible enough (maybe annotated with `@VisibleForTesting`) to call from your test.

Other option: Factor out the injector-setting (or module creation) and test that separately as a static method.